# How to create dynamic node relation in neo4j for dynamic data?

Tags: neo4j

I was able to create author nodes directly from the json file . But the challenge is on what basis or how we have to link the data. Linking "Author" to "organization". since the data is dynamic we cannot generalize it. I have tried with using csv file but, it fails the conditions when dynamic data is coming. For example one json record contain 2 organization and 3 authors, next record will be different. Different json record have different author and organization to link.  organization/1 represent organization1 and organization/2 represents organization 2.  Any help or hint will be great. Thank you. Please find the json file below.

```
"Author": [
{
  "seq": "3",
  "type": "abc",
  "identifier": [
    {
      "idtype:auid": "10000000"
    }
  ],
  "familyName": "xyz",
  "indexedName": "MI",
  "givenName": "T",
    "preferredName": {
    "familyName": "xyz1",
    "givenName": "a",
    "initials": "T.",
    "indexedName": "bT."
  },
  "emailAddressList": [],
  "degrees": [],
  "@id": "https:abc/2009127993/author/person/3",
  "hasAffiliation": [
    "https:abc/author/organization/1"
  ],
  "organization": [
[
  {
    "identifier": [
      {
        "@type": "idtype:uuid",
        "@subtype": "idsubtype:affiliationInstanceId",
        "@value": "aff2"
      },
      {
        "@type": "idtype:OrgDB",
        "@subtype": "idsubtype:afid",
        "@value": "12345"
      },
      {
        "@type": "idtype:OrgDB",
        "@subtype": "idsubtype:dptid"
      }
    ],
    "organizations": [],
    "addressParts": [],
    "sourceText": "",
    "text": " Medical University School of Medicine",
    "@id": "https:abc/author/organization/1"
  }
  ],
  
  [
  {
    "identifier": [
      {
        "@type": "idtype:uuid",
        "@subtype": "idsubtype:affiliationInstanceId",
        "@value": "aff1"
      },
      {
        "@type": "idtype:OrgDB",
        "@subtype": "idsubtype:afid",
        "@value": "7890"
      },
      {
        "@type": "idtype:OrgDB",
        "@subtype": "idsubtype:dptid"
      }
    ],
    "organizations": [],
    "addressParts": [],
    "sourceText": "",
    "text": "K  University",
    "@id": "https:efg/author/organization/2"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi I see that Organisation is part of the Author data, so you have to model it like wise. So for instance (Author)-[:AFFILIATED_WITH]->(Organisation)

When you use apoc.load.json which supports a stream of author objects you can load the data.

I did some checks on your JSON structure with this cypher query:

```
call apoc.load.json("file:///Users/keesv/work/check.json") yield value
unwind value as record
WITH record.Author as author
WITH author.identifier[0].`idtype:auid` as authorId,author,  author.organization[0] as organizations
return authorId, author, organizations
```

To get this working you will need to create include apoc in the plugins directory, and add the following two lines in the apoc.conf file (create one if it is not there) in the 'conf' directory.

```
apoc.import.file.enabled=true
apoc.import.file.use_neo4j_config=false
```

I also see a nested array for the organisations in the output why is that and what is the meaning of that?

And finally I see also in the JSON that an organisation can have a reference to other organisations.

explanation
In my query I use UNWIND to unwind the base Author array. This means you get for every author a 'record' to work with.

With a MERGE or CREATE statement you can now create an Author Node with the correct properties. With the FOREACH construct you can walk over all the Organization entry and create/merge an Organization node and create the relation between the Author and the Organization.

here an 'psuedo' example

```
call apoc.load.json("file:///Users/keesv/work/check.json") yield value
unwind value as record
WITH record.Author as author
WITH author.identifier[0].`idtype:auid` as authorId,author,  author.organization[0] as organizations
// creating the Author node
MERGE (a:Author { id: authorId })
SET a.familyName = author.familyName
...
// walk over the organizations
// determine 
FOREACH (org in organizations | 
  MERGE (o:Organization { id: ... })
  SET o.name = org.text
  ...
  MERGE (a)-[:AFFILIATED_WITH]->(o)
  // if needed you can also do a nested FOREACH here to process the Org Org relationship
)
```

Here is the JSON file I used I had to change something at the start and the end

```
[
   {
      "Author":{
         "seq":"3",
         "type":"abc",
         "identifier":[
            {
               "idtype:auid":"10000000"
            }
         ],
         "familyName":"xyz",
         "indexedName":"MI",
         "givenName":"T",
         "preferredName":{
            "familyName":"xyz1",
            "givenName":"a",
            "initials":"T.",
            "indexedName":"bT."
         },
         "emailAddressList":[
            
         ],
         "degrees":[
            
         ],
         "@id":"https:abc/2009127993/author/person/3",
         "hasAffiliation":[
            "https:abc/author/organization/1"
         ],
         "organization":[
            [
               {
                  "identifier":[
                     {
                        "@type":"idtype:uuid",
                        "@subtype":"idsubtype:affiliationInstanceId",
                        "@value":"aff2"
                     },
                     {
                        "@type":"idtype:OrgDB",
                        "@subtype":"idsubtype:afid",
                        "@value":"12345"
                     },
                     {
                        "@type":"idtype:OrgDB",
                        "@subtype":"idsubtype:dptid"
                     }
                  ],
                  "organizations":[
                     
                  ],
                  "addressParts":[
                     
                  ],
                  "sourceText":"",
                  "text":" Medical University School of Medicine",
                  "@id":"https:abc/author/organization/1"
               }
            ],
            [
               {
                  "identifier":[
                     {
                        "@type":"idtype:uuid",
                        "@subtype":"idsubtype:affiliationInstanceId",
                        "@value":"aff1"
                     },
                     {
                        "@type":"idtype:OrgDB",
                        "@subtype":"idsubtype:afid",
                        "@value":"7890"
                     },
                     {
                        "@type":"idtype:OrgDB",
                        "@subtype":"idsubtype:dptid"
                     }
                  ],
                  "organizations":[
                     
                  ],
                  "addressParts":[
                     
                  ],
                  "sourceText":"",
                  "text":"K  University",
                  "@id":"https:efg/author/organization/2"
               }
            ]
         ]
      }
   }
]
```

IMPORTANT create unique constraints for Author.id and Organization.id!!

In this way you can process any json file with an unknown number of author elements and an unknown number of affiliated organisations

Comment: the problem i think is the [1] are you sure there are two organizations? You can also use other list operations. 
...[ y in organization.identifier where y.`@subtype` = 'idsubtype:afid' | y.`@value`][0] as orgId. What is the error message?